# JsonDeserialize returns null for some strings (only for some)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a quite large Json into a C# class I made.
All of the objects in the class are deserialized correctly, but JsonConvert has trouble with two objects. They are strings in C# and some of the strings are returned correctly, others are empty. As the Json is really big (30MB) I´m only able to post a small extract here, but it should give you an idea of how the JSON is structured:

```
"attributes" : {
        "AnzahlFall" : 1,
        "Meldedatum" : 1585612800000, 
        "IdLandkreis" : "08327", 
        "Datenstand" : "26.10.2020, 00:00 Uhr", 
      }
```

This is one of many fields. The problematic strings are "IdLandkreis" and "Datenstand". There is no way that any of these Values are null or empty in the Json File, but what I get after deserializing and serializing again is this:

```
"attributes" : 
{"AnzahlFall":1,
"NeuerFall":0,
"Meldedatum":1601510400000,
"DatenStand":null,
"idLandkreis":null
}
```

This is the whole C# Part:

```
    public class Attributes
{
    public int AnzahlFall { get; set; }

    public int NeuerFall { get; set; }

    public long Meldedatum { get; set; }

    public string DatenStand { get; set; }

    public string idLandkreis { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
}


public class Caselist
{

    public bool exceededTransferLimit { get; set; }


    public List<Report> features { get; set; }

}
```

and I use this to call the JsonConverter:

Caselist rki_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(readData());

What I tried:

- Use other data types such as int for "iDLandkreis" -> is still 0

I renamed the variables, but nothing changes. When parsing through Caselist, the output looks somwhat like this:

Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid

The data is about Covid-19 and is presented by a local science insitute from Germany

You can get a part of the data here (it is split in many files):

https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_COVID19/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=IdLandkreis,AnzahlFall,Meldedatum,NeuerFall,Datenstand&outSR=4326&f=json

I´d be very thankful for your help.

Greetings,
Jonathan

Comment: What data type are those properties in your c# model? What code are you running to do the deserialization?

Comment: Added the information to the post

Comment: `Datenstand` in json and `DatenStand` in poco. Use `[JsonProperty("Datenstand")]` if you want to keep your poco name but the serialized name should be different

Answer (score 1):

`Datenstand` in json and `DatenStand` in poco. Use `[JsonProperty("Datenstand")]` if you want to keep your poco name but the serialized name should be different

So you would have something like this in your poco:

```
public class Attributes
{
    public int AnzahlFall { get; set; }
    public int NeuerFall { get; set; }
    public long Meldedatum { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Datenstand")]
    public string DatenStand { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("IdLandkreis")]
    public string idLandkreis { get; set; }
}
```

The bigger problem I see from your C# is that you don't seem to have a standard naming convention. Normally you would use PascalCasing for your C# and camlCasing for json files.

If you would have this setup, you could also set your [default settings](https://andrewlock.net/serializing-a-pascalcase-newtonsoft-json-jobject-to-camelcase/) to

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```

Comment: If I parste through the Objects, the output still looks like this:   01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid 01060Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid Landkreisid

Comment: @Jonnyb170 Can you share your JSON in the OP? Also potentially, if you have some default settings or a contractresolver set already? At least enough so one can verify what you are getting, as now it seems it's not really reproducible

Comment: Added a link to the data. Sorry I don´t now a lot about coding, so I don´t really know what  a contractresolver is. But I probably didn´t as I didn´t change anything to the JsonConvert at all.

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive. I think the issue comes from your property names :

- DatenStand != Datenstand
- idLandkreis != IdLandkreis

Seb

Comment: You can work around this by specifying a ```JsonSerializerOptions``` with ```PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true```. See [JsonSerializerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=netcore-3.1#properties).

Comment: While c# is case sensitive, Json.Net is not. It is case insensitive _by default_. It will match properties when the casing is different just fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOsfsM

Comment: @gunr2171 isn't that an assumption on how the defaultSettings might be set?

Comment: @gunr2171 This is incorrect for ```System.Text.Json```. From the Microsoft Documentation
> PropertyNameCaseInsensitive: Gets or sets a value that determines whether a property's name uses a case-insensitive comparison during deserialization. The default value is false.

Comment: @DouglasRiddle that might be incorrect for Microsoft's json library, but this question is tagged "Json.Net" and the code being used comes from that library.

Comment: renamed it, but the output is still null for some outputs -> look at my comment of the other post

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It wasn´t a problem with my code or JsonConvert it all.
I just forgot to put the particular objects in the query of the JSON request. The Json file I posted here, was not the one I downloaded in my code. I downloaded the wrong one.